# Hide the comments when writing the Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, revision-control

I added some comments to the word document I'm writing, but I don't want to display them on my screen. This is what I see now:

[image: image description]

I want to hide the grey panel that contains the red blocks. I tried configuring print settings:

[image: image description]

Unchecking the print revisions checkbox hides the revisions from print review, but not from the editor.

How to hide revisions from the editor screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about in your language, but under the `Review` tab, you can turn off `Markup`.

Here's an image from Word 2016, where `No Markup` removes all of this from the editor and print.

[image]

In other versions it may say `Final` instead, where you are likely on `Final Showing Markup`

Comment: It says Final. But what I actually needed is right below that which simply says "Display revisions" in my language.